# Pretix-Widget open always in a new Tab

Tags: javascript, html

I have been trying to embeded a pretix-widget to keep customers on my site, but every time I press buy, a new tap opens.
it should look like in the Pretix-documentation (https://docs.pretix.eu/en/latest/user/events/widget.html#example), that it is overlayed over the page.

I also tried it with an Iframe(here, pretix.eu block the request) and with window.open(), but it doesn't work.

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://pretix.eu/demo/democon/widget/v1.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://pretix.eu/widget/v1.en.js" async></script>
</head>

<body>
<pretix-widget event="https://pretix.eu/demo/democon/"></pretix-widget>
<noscript>
   <div class="pretix-widget">
        <div class="pretix-widget-info-message">
            JavaScript is disabled in your browser. To access our ticket shop without JavaScript,
            please <a target="_blank" href="https://pretix.eu/demo/democon/">click here</a>.
        </div>
    </div>
</noscript>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you getting any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0):

It´s solved, because it was local i have to add "skip-ssl-check"

```
<pretix-widget event="https://pretix.eu/demo/democon/" skip-ssl-check></pretix-widget>
```